# Norm of an operator formed using a unitary operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces, norms

Suppose, $ A $ is a unitary matrix in $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $ given by $ (a_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n} $ which has the property that, for all the basis elements $ e_i $, $ Ae_i\ne |\lambda| e_j $ for all $i,j $ and $ |\lambda|=1 $. Then consider the matrix $ B=(a_{i,j}^4)_{1\le i,j\le n} $. Then is it true that $ ||B||< 1 $?

I could prove that, $ ||B||\le 1 $, but I want to know if its strictly less than 1 in this case.

Also is it possible to get such a matrix $ A $ for which $ ||B||=1 $ and $ B $ actually attends its norm when $ A $ is a operator on a infinite dimensional Hilbert space with basis $ \{e_i\}_i $?

Edit: Will Sawin already posted a solution for the finite dimensional case. So I just edited the infinite dimensional case and added a condition I forgot to mention earlier.

Comment: How do you prove it's at most $1$?

Comment: I will add the proof for at most 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show $||B||<1$ (in the finite-dimensional case). Suppose $|Bv|=|v|$ for some nonzero $v$. Then as $|Bv|$ is the projection of $A^{\otimes 4} ( \sum_i v_i e_i^{\otimes 4})$ onto the subspace generated by $e_i^{\otimes 4}$, and $|A^{\otimes 4} ( \sum_i v_i e_i^{\otimes 4})|=| \sum_i v_i e_i^{\otimes 4}|=|v|$, it follows that $A^{\otimes 4} ( \sum_i v_i e_i^{\otimes 4})$ lies in the space generated by $e_i^{\otimes 4}$.

In other words, for each $j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4$ not all equal, we have $\sum_i A_{ij_1} A_{ij_2} A_{ij_3} A_{ij_4} v_i =0$.  Now suppose $j_1,j_2,j_3$ are not all equal, then $j_4$ can be anything and this equation will still apply. Because $A_{ij_4}$ for different values of $j_4$ form a basis, it follows that for all $i$, for all $j_1,j_2,j_3$ not all equal. $A_{ij_1} A_{ij_2} A_{ij_3} v_i=0$. Take some $i$ such that $v_i$ is not zero. By assumption on $A$ there are $j$ and $k$ such that neither $A_{ij}$ nor $A_{ik}$ vanishes. Taking $j_1=j,j_2=k,j_3=k$ we get a contradiction. So $|Bv|<|v|$ for all nonzero $v$ and the norm is less than $1$.

In the infinite-dimensional case, it can equal exactly one. Consider an operator on $l^2$ given by an infinite block-diagonal matrix with two-by-two blocks, each a two-by-two unitary matrix, and converging to a diagonal matrix but never actually reaching it. Then the fourth power will have blocks converging to a two-by-two unitary diagonal matrix, hence with norm converging to $1$, so the fourth power has norm $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But in the infinite dimensional case is it possible for the operator $ B $ to actually attend its norm? I mean is there an example for which there will be a $ v $ with $ |v|=1 $ so that $ |Bv|=1 $. Since any operator in finite dimension attends its norm, I forgot to mention it in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't read the solution earlier. I see that its not possible for $B$ to attend the norm in infinite dimension also. The same proof works.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take the unitary
$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$
which satisfies your assumption. The matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}$
has norm 1.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $ Ae_i\ne \lambda e_j $ for all $ |\lambda|=1 $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof for $ ||B||\le 1$(This still doesn't answer the question):-
Consider the vector space $ \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^n$.
There consider the subspace spanned by $ e_i^{\otimes 4} $. Then $ e_i^{\otimes 4} $ forms a orthonormal basis for this subspace. And the matrix for $ A\otimes A\otimes A\otimes A$ restricted to this subspace wrt this basis is exactly $ B $. And we know that $ ||A^{\otimes 4}||=||A||^4=1 $. So $ ||B||\le 1$.